# Why does Quickbooks drop class and account values when I send Invoice?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, quickbooks

I am trying to set the class_ref and ar_account_ref values in quickbooks. but it drops them when I submit the changes. My local object looks like this:

```
{
           "global_tax_calculation" => nil,
                               "id" => nil,
                       "sync_token" => nil,
                        "meta_data" => nil,
                    "custom_fields" => nil,
                  "auto_doc_number" => nil,
                       "doc_number" => nil,
                         "txn_date" => "2014-12-31T16:46:04+00:00",
                     "currency_ref" => nil,
                    "exchange_rate" => nil,
                     "private_note" => nil,
              "linked_transactions" => nil,
                       "line_items" => [
    [0] #<Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem id: nil, line_num: nil, description: nil, amount: 50000.0, detail_type: SalesItemLineDetail, sales_line_item_detail: {"item_ref"=>nil, "class_ref"=>nil, "unit_price"=>50000.0, "rate_percent"=>nil, "price_level_ref"=>nil, "quantity"=>1, "tax_code_ref"=>nil, "service_date"=>"2014-12-31T16:46:04+00:00"}, sub_total_line_detail: nil, payment_line_detail: nil, discount_line_detail: nil>
],
                   "txn_tax_detail" => nil,
                     "customer_ref" => {
     "name" => nil,
    "value" => 97,
     "type" => nil
},
                    "customer_memo" => nil,
                  "billing_address" => nil,
                 "shipping_address" => nil,
                        "class_ref" => {
     "name" => nil,
    "value" => 5000000000000001652,
     "type" => nil
},
                   "sales_term_ref" => nil,
                         "due_date" => nil,
                  "ship_method_ref" => nil,
                        "ship_date" => nil,
                     "tracking_num" => nil,
                   "ar_account_ref" => {
     "name" => nil,
    "value" => 33,
     "type" => nil
},
                     "total_amount" => 50000.0,
                "home_total_amount" => nil,
        "apply_tax_after_discount?" => nil,
                     "print_status" => nil,
                     "email_status" => nil,
                          "balance" => nil,
                          "deposit" => nil,
                   "department_ref" => nil,
               "allow_ipn_payment?" => nil,
                       "bill_email" => nil,
            "allow_online_payment?" => nil,
"allow_online_credit_card_payment?" => nil,
        "allow_online_ach_payment?" => nil
}
```

But when I commit my changes and grab the invoice object back from Quickbooks, customer_ref and ar_account_ref both return nil. I am using the Quickbooks Ruby Gem and all of the other params I pass work fine. I have tried setting the object with:

```
  invoice.class_ref = Quickbooks::Model::BaseReference.new(33)
  invoice.class_id = Quickbooks::Model::BaseReference.new(33)
  invoice.class_id = 33
  invoice.class_ref = 33
```

Any suggestions? Interestingly enough, I am able to create a line_item with  a class and get that setting to stick. So, I am under the impression that the problem lies with Quickbooks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same question - You can not pass class_ref or ar_account_ref directly to Invoice. I contacted QB and they replied:

"Invoice by Class is supported.
Invoice picks up the Accounts for the Items added in lines. Separately adding accounts is not supported by the product, so service does not support it.
Adding account in future is not in plan. QB Enterprise and QBO are different.
Templates support is not yet planned."